# Python3.10 doesn't support legacy docker-compose, how can I use docker compose programatically in a Python code?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, python-3.10

Couple years ago I have been using `docker-compose` as a `venv/` module, however it has been deprecated and now you can only run `docker compose` via Docker CLI.

I have been searching for that functionality in `pydocker`, but unfortunately didn't find anything related to `compose` functionality.

Does it mean that from now on the call to `docker compose` should be initiated via `subprocess.run(["docker", "compose", ...])` ?

Or there any alternatives to access `docker compose` functionality programmatically (inside a Python code).

P.S Python 3.10 also warns that `docker-compose` legacy module will be fully unavailable in autumn 2023.